# What would I need to code in order for one user to download files from another users computer, through a website?

Tags: java, python, flash, websocket

I am trying to make a web application where a user can leave his computer on, and multiple other users can download a specified file off of his computer. **But** without a main server... so the user's computer would be the server. (maybe some how like limewire did it?) **And most importantly** it all has to be on a website... no program to download.

I wasnt sure but I think this might be the solution:
http://goo.gl/jduME
,but im not sure...

Please & Thanks. And some code would **really** be appreciated.

Umm, it may be possible... the user would have to specify WHICH file theyd allow for others to download.

Comment: Even assuming it was possible, which it isn't, who on earth would be silly enough to allow a random website to upload anything from their computer?

Answer (score 2):

It's not possible without the user downloading and explicitly installing something, it's for obvious security reasons!!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I missed something in your description but as I see it you just described an ordinary website. you could run a webserver on the computer with directory listing of some kind and just let people browse there and get the files... 
The computer is the server and the clients don't have to download and client software.

Whats the question here?

Answer (score 0):

I would go the route of writing a Java application that can be started using Java Web Start, this way the user doesn't have to download and install anything directly. You can then embed a web server like Jetty to do the actual file serving, as well as host the admin pages of what files should be served, etc.

Here is an example of how to run Jetty in a Java Web Start application which should help you get started http://hbjastad.blogspot.com/2010/01/running-embedded-jetty-in-java-web.html